# Rails .where any field contains specific text

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there a short-hand way of querying a Rails database for any record that has a field containing a specific piece of text? I know I could code every field with a `.where("field_name LIKE ?", "my text")`, but I have several fields and am wondering if there is a shorter way of doing this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "if there is a shorter way of doing this" - probably not. Write this method once and hide in a helper. Bam, there's your shortcut.

Comment: Multiple values you can use `REGEXP` but multiple fields need to be specified. Use scopes if you need the same query params on different models.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I do not know of a framework-way to do so. You could code something using

```
my_attributes = YourModel.attributes
# delete attributes you do not need, like `id` etc.
# or just create an array with your desired attributes,
# whichever way is faster
queries = my_attributes.map { |attr| "#{attr} LIKE %insert_your_text_here%" } 
# Do not use this if the text your looking for is provided by user input.
built_query = queries.join(" OR ")
YourModel.where(built_query)
```

This could bring you closer to your goal. Let me know if this makes sense to you.

edit: The answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/49458059/299781 mentions Ransack. That's a nice gem and takes the load off of you. Makes it easier, nicer and performs better :D

**Glad you like this, but pay attention that you make your app open for sql injection, if you take user-input as the text you are looking for. (with this solution)** Ransack would alleviate that.

Comment: I'm liking this. Thanks!

Comment: Can you not wrap it in `Arel.sql("#{attr} LIKE .....")` to be safe from sql injections?

Answer (score 1):

```
class MyModel
    scope :search_like, -> (field_name, search_string) {where("#{field_name} LIKE ?", "%#{search_string}%")}
end
```

then you can call it like:

```
MyModal.search_like('name', 'foobar')
```

UPDATE based on @holgar answer but beware if not indexed these searches can be slow on large data sets:

```
class MyModel
  def self.multi_like(search_string)
    my_attributes = [:first_name, :last_name] # probalby only use string fields here
    queries = my_attributes.map { |attr| "#{attr} LIKE '%#{search_string}%'" }
    where(queries.join(" OR "))
  end   
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want full fledge text search based on params then you can use [ransack](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack) gem